# How to remove duplicate items in nested list?

Tags: list, haskell, functional-programming

I have a Haskel function called flatten that works as such:

```
flatten :: [[a]] -> [a] 
flatten []            = []
flatten ([]:vs)       = flatten vs
flatten ((x:xs):vs)   = x:flatten (xs:vs)
```

It takes a list of lists and combines it into one list. How can I make another function called flatten2set that works exactly like flatten (or calls flatten), but removes all duplicates, if any? I want to try and do this without tools like nub.

An example would be:

```
flatten2set [[1],[5,1,4],[9,1,3],[2,5]] --> [1,5,4,9,3,2]
```

I have attempted to implement a nub function:

```
nub:: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
nub (x:xs) = x : filter (/=x) (myNub xs)
nub [] = []
```

And when I have tried to use it like this:

```
flatten2set :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten2set[x] = (myNub . flatten) [x]
```

I receive this error:

testing.hs:20:18: error:

```
• No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘myNub’
  Possible fix:
    add (Eq a) to the context of
      the type signature for:
        flatten2set :: forall a. [[a]] -> [a]
• In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘myNub’
  In the expression: myNub . flatten
  In the expression: (myNub . flatten) [x]
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `flatten2set = nub . flatten`, and `flatten = concat`.

Comment: I am sorry, you're right, but I forgot to add that I want to do this without any predefined libraries.

Comment: Try just implementing `nub`, then, and you’ll be safe to define `flatten2set = nub . flatten`.

Comment: @Ryan, I have tried implementing my own nub, and trying to call the function like you did is giving me an error, can you help out?

Comment: Can you edit your attempt and the error into your question?

Comment: @Ryan, I have made some edits. I would appreciate any help

Comment: You’re matching the parameter `[x]`, but then writing `mynub. flatten` rather than `(mynub . flatten) [x]`. Hence the type error.

Comment: @Davislor, after adding your edit and trying again I have gotten another error. I have edited the question to reflect that, can you help?

Comment: Your latest error is basically the compiler telling you that your myNub function expects Eq a, but you're calling it from flatten2set, which doesn't make any guarantees about the parameter being a member of the Eq typeclass.  You can follow the instructions from the compiler and add an Eq a => constraint to your function...

Comment: @MarcTalbot, you are right. That took care of it! Now I am getting an error about having non exhaustive patters in flatten2set.

Comment: That’s because your pattern guards have to match every possible list, and `[x]` only matches singletons.

Comment: Do I need a third guard for something such as (x:xs)?

Comment: Typically you might match `[]` and  then `(x:xs)`, since every list either has no elements or at least one element. So those two guards are, between them, exhaustive.

Answer (score 3):

You have an excellent implementation of `myNub`

```
myNub :: Eq a => [a] -> [a]
myNub (x:xs) = x : filter (/=x) (myNub xs)
myNub [] = []
```

Then you try to call it

```
flatten2set :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten2set = myNub . flatten
```

But you've declared that `flatten2set` works for *any* `a`. The compiler is simply pointing out that that cannot be. What if we tried to call `flatten2set` with a list of lists of functions? It won't work because `myNub` requires `Eq` and functions are not comparable. Since we call a function that requires `Eq a`, we too must require `Eq a`.

```
flatten2set :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
flatten2set = myNub . flatten
```

I took the liberty of removing the `[x]`, which had no purpose. If you really want to have an argument, you just name the argument. There's no need to pattern match on it.

```
flatten2set :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [a]
flatten2set x = (myNub . flatten) x
```

Using `[x]` is an assertion that, in this case, the list will contain exactly one element, and we want `flatten2set` to work on lists containing any number of elements.